# jfrog rt del 404 could not locate artifact

Tags: jfrog-cli

I am using the jfrog CLI.
I use the same values for "rt" : config, upload, search.
But it breaks when I try a "delete".
It partially works in that it finds the file for a delete when it looks it up, but when it tries to delete the file object, it adds a REPO: /path and then errors.
Any ideas as to why it uses a "REPO: /path" versus "repo/path"?
Search finds it with the "repo/path"?

Code:
jfrog rt delete --user=xxxx --password=##### -url=https://server.domain/artifactory  REPO_NAME/dir/dir/dir/dir/file.rpm

Get:
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 1 artifact.
  AXONE-YUM/soup/axone-layer-zero/CentOS/matt/GeoIP-1.5.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
Are you sure you want to delete the above paths? (y/n): y
[Info] Deleting: AXONE-YUM/soup/axone-layer-zero/CentOS/matt/GeoIP-1.5.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
[Error] Artifactory response: 404 Not Found

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Could not locate artifact 'AXONE-YUM:soup/axone-layer-zero/CentOS/matt/GeoIP-1.5.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm'."
    }
  ]
}
{
  "status": "failure",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

install jfrog CLI

Add proper certificate to .jrog folder

Run below:

```
jfrog rt c

#Enter server url

#API Key: blank

user ID

Password
```

Now it encrypts password. You are ready to go.

Try

```
jfrog rt del repo path/version/ --quiet=true
```

(no need of full url, straight from repo)

Comment: welcome to SO, please edit your answer style to increase readability, mark commands as code, avoid using bold font weight if it's not really necessary.