# "Could not locate artifact" when uploading artifact that already exists?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm trying to upload artifacts using the following command:

```bash
jf rt upload "/local/dir/" my-repo/path/to/ --recursive --url my.artifactory.server.com --flat --access-token $JFROG_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This works fine if the file doesn't exist in the specified location. But if a file already exists--I want to overwrite it, but I get the following error:

```json
04:42:17 [Warn] [Thread 1] (Attempt 4) - Failure occurred while uploading to https://my.artifactory.server.com/artifactory/my-repo/path/to/file.pdf: server response: 404 Not Found
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not locate artifact 'my-repo:path/to/file.pdf'."
  } ]
}
04:42:17 [Info] [Thread 1]  executor timeout after 3 attempts with 0 milliseconds wait intervals
04:42:17 [Error] server response: 404 Not Found
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53039661/22146392) to the same error that recommended `jfrog rt c` to store the credentials, but as far as I can tell that's an interactive command and I'm running this in a script so interactive isn't an option.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Edit: Just tested and I get the same error with `jf rt del`. I can upload the artifact (if it doesn't already exist) with `jf rt upload` and I can find it with `jf rt s`, so it definitely exists. Would this be a permissions issue? Maybe I don't have permissions to delete?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't have "delete" permissions to the Artifactory repository. I was able to get those permissions and now it's working as expected.

It's unfortunate that Artifactory doesn't return accurate error codes.

Answer (score -1):

I configurned CLI with Access Token and it is working fine. I have a file already present now I tried to upload the same file(to override), Also, I have added one more file to check if old and new files are getting uploaded succssfully.

```
jf rt upload /path/mydirectory/ example-repo-local/new/ --flat
07:56:16 [Info] These files were uploaded:

 example-repo-local
└──  new
    ├──  gradle-wrapper.jar
    └──  maven-wrapper.jar
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 2,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

My CLI version is 2.54.0
My Artifactory version is 7.81.2
Maybe you are testing in lower versions of CLI/Artifactory. [image: Before upload]
[image: After trying to upload existing file]

Comment: When you say you "configurned CLI with Access Token", what procedures did you follow to accomplish that? I tried `jf c add --url $JFROG_URL --access-token $JFROG_ACCESS_TOKEN` from [this doc](https://docs.jfrog-applications.jfrog.io/jfrog-applications/jfrog-cli/cli-for-jfrog-artifactory/authentication#authenticating-with-an-access-token) and I'm getting the error `The provided access token is not a valid JWT, probably a reference token`. This is the same access token that works with `jf rt upload --access-token $JFROG_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Comment: Login to Artfactory > Right side top user Drop down > User Profile > Authenticaton Settings > Generate Identity token. 
`jf c add` 
`Enter a unique server identifier: myart`
 `JFrog Plat form URL: https://myart.jfrog.io/`
 `JFrog username: XXXXXX`
`JFrog password or API key: API key`
Pass the API key that was generated in the above step. 
I believe it could be an issue wth the versions.

Comment: I said in the question this needs to be fully non-interactive. It's for a script so there is no way to respond to prompts.